# Operator '+' cannot be called on 'String?' because it is potentially null. In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am trying to make an app which takes names then validates it. I got which says : The operator '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. I tried to write ' if (value != null), but then i got another error.

```
Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: animeler.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

            return ListTile(title:
                Text(animeler[index].animeName +
                " : " +
                animeler[index].animePoint.toString()),
                
        })),
```

This is the class :

```
class Animes {
  String? animeName = "";
  double animePoint = 0;
  String animeLover = "";


  Animes(String animeName, double animePoint, String animeLover) {
    this.animeName = animeName;
    this.animePoint = animePoint;
    this.animeLover = animeLover;
  }

  
}
```

This is where i got the anime name. I have a variable anime.

```
  Widget buildFirstNameField()
  {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Anime name", hintText: "Death Note"),
      validator: vallval,
      onSaved: (String? value)
      {
        anime.animeName = value;

      },
    );
  }
}
```

i call the 'buildFirstNameField' function in:

```
body: Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: Form(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        buildFirstNameField(),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animeName` is a nullable String, so it is possible to get null, you can provide default value on null case like `myNullableVariable ?? defaultValue`

But you can use String format here,

```dart
 Text("${animeler[index].animeName??""} : ${animeler[index].animePoint.toString()}")
```

Comment: Can you please tell me, what exactly this code does? Thank you.

Comment: `myNullableVariable ?? ` check the left part if it is null or not. if null then provide empty string `""`,  `${varName}` will return value  and place the rest. You can find more about [String](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.0/dart-core/String-class.html)

Comment: btw if you provide empty string you can remove null sign `String? animeName = "";` to `String animeName = "";`

Answer (score 1):

because you already set a default value in your model class you can use `!` and by that you tell to compiler that you are sure that your variable(`animeName`) isn't `null`:

```
ListTile(
   title: Text(animeler[index].animeName! +
         " : " + animeler[index].animePoint.toString()),
)
```

This is because you set `String? animeName` as nullable variable in your model.